# How to know component is ready to render?

Tags: react-native, uicomponents

I am new in `React-Native` and I am stuck at one place to do in `React-Native`.

This is my one component :-

```
const ConentQR = (
  content: string,
  logo: Image.propTypes.source,
  logoSize: number,
) => {
  return (
    <QRCode
      color={Colors.DARK_PURPLE}
      content={content}
      codeStyle={'dot'}
      outerEyeStyle={'diamond'}
      logo={logo}
      logoSize={logoSize}
      backgroundColor={'transparent'}
    />
  );
};
```

The problem is I am facing in react native,This component (`<QRCode`) take some time to generate QR, so how I can put this block in any background thread so that I can show loader to user until it get prepared. I am getting stuck at this place and unable to resolve that for while.
Please help anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `InteractionManager` to schedule tasks in the background

```js
import { InteractionManager } from 'react-native'

const ConentQR = (
  content: string,
  logo: Image.propTypes.source,
  logoSize: number,
) => {
  // Use a state variable to track the QR code
  const [qrCode, setQrCode] = useState(null)

  // Use the InteractionManager to run the generation process in the background
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    // Generate the QR code in the background
    const qrCode = generateQRCode(content, logo, logoSize)
    setQrCode(qrCode)
  })

  // Show a loading spinner while the QR code is generated 
  // so the user knows something is happening in the background
  if (!qrCode) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />
  }

  // Render the QR code when it's ready
  return <QRCode {...qrCode} />
}
```

I am using `useState` to keep track on the qr code and `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` to schedule the generation in the background. If the qr code is not ready it displays a loader. The generation happens in the `generateQRCode()` function.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me, Learned some new today

Comment: can we show a loader until QR set to UI as well, it taking time to set to UI as well

Comment: @PankajSonava it definitly is possible. I am unable to do it now, I will give you the code in a few hours

Comment: Yeah please share

Comment: @PankajSonava I edited my answer. I don't know if it works because I am unable to test right now

Comment: Noah not getting you, can you please update some more brief ?

Comment: Check this one please

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74906346/how-to-set-ui-component-to-state-in-background-in-react-native