# how to set UI component to state in background in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am new in `react-native`, in my application I am generating `QRCode` by one library and it working but in `android` it is taking time to show on UI, when I set that component to `hook` to show on UI then it stuck for while and every thing getting non-responsive. After some time it shows and everything work well.
So how can put that `setWalletQR` in background so that I can show loader until it show to UI?

Here is my code where I am generating the QR in InteractionManager to show

```
const PozReceive = ({ onClose }: ReceiveProps) => {
  const [walletQR, setWalletQR] = useState<ConentQR>(null);

const generateWalletQrCode = () => {
    const interactionPromise = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      const qrCode = ConentQR(user?.walletAddress || '', walletImg, 50);
      setWalletQR(qrCode);
    });
    return () => interactionPromise.cancel();
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (!pouchQR) {
      generatePouchQrCode();
    }
  }, []);

return (
    <Modal
      coverScreen={true}
      isVisible={true}
      onBackdropPress={onClose}
      onBackButtonPress={onClose}
      backdropColor={Colors.DARK_PURPLE}
      backdropOpacity={0.7}
      style={styles.modal}>
      <>
        <BlurView
          style={styles.blurView}
          blurType="dark"
          blurAmount={20}
          reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
        />
        <VStack style={[styles.modalContainer]}>
           {!walletQR ? (
             <Image style={styles.qrLoader} source={loaderGif} />
            ) : (
            walletQR
           )}
   </VStack>
  </>
 </Modal>
);
};
```

and here is QR code generator code :-

```
const ContentQR = (
  content: string,
  logo: Image.propTypes.source,
  logoSize: number,
  backgroundColor: string = 'transparent',
) => {
  return (
    <QRCode
      color={Colors.DARK_PURPLE}
      content={content}
      codeStyle={'dot'}
      outerEyeStyle={'diamond'}
      logo={logo}
      logoSize={logoSize}
      backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
    />
  );
};
```

Someone please help me I getting stuck here for while.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a variable `isLoading` and render the loader based on this variable instead of qr value.

```js
const PozReceive = ({ onClose }: ReceiveProps) => {
  const [walletQR, setWalletQR] = useState<ConentQR>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<Boolean>(false);

const generateWalletQrCode = () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const interactionPromise = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      const qrCode = ConentQR(user?.walletAddress || '', walletImg, 50);
      setWalletQR(qrCode);
      setIsLoading(false)
    });
    return () => interactionPromise.cancel();
  };

....

<VStack style={[styles.modalContainer]}>
{isLoading && <Image style={styles.qrLoader} source={loaderGif} />}
{!isLoaing && walletQR && walletQR}
</VStack>
```

Comment: Already tried not working, UI getting stuck for while when this line execute ```setWalletQR(qrCode);```

Comment: @PankajSonava can you record a video?

Comment: here is the video link where my UI get stuck for while 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kik4vrru4047i5/XRecorder_27122022_164206.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @PankajSonava hmm can you check the performance monitor, probably your JS thread was blocked for a couple of seconds by QR code generation. Which library do you use for QR?

Comment: I have used this package ```react-native-custom-qr-codes``` and I checked Pref monitor as wall UI thread and JS thread it shows around 50

Comment: @PankajSonava try to debug it with Flipper and FlameGraph from React Profiler

Comment: Okay, suppose it is blocking the JS thread then what will be the solution